# Monolog composer.json is not working

Tags: json, monolog

I got this error trying to install Monolog, I've tried to install it using `sudo` command, but still it will not work. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.4.10 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.7.0 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.4.11 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.7.0 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.4.12 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.4.9 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.7.0 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.5.0 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.5.1 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.5.2 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.5.3 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.5.4 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.0 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.1 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.10 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.11 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.12 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.13 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.14 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.15 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.16 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.2 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.3 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.4 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.5 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.6 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.7 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.8 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.6.9 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.0, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.7.0 requires guzzle/guzzle >=3.7, satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.7.1 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.7 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.7.2 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.7 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.7.3 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.7 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.7.4 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.7 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.7.5 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.7 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.7.6 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.7 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 2.7.7 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.7 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.8.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.8.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.7.4 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.7.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.7.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.7.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.7.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for aws/aws-sdk-php ~2.4, >2.4.8 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[2.4.10, 2.4.11, 2.4.12, 2.4.9, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.10, 2.6.11, 2.6.12, 2.6.13, 2.6.14, 2.6.15, 2.6.16, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.6.6, 2.6.7, 2.6.8, 2.6.9, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.7.6, 2.7.7].
```

```
{
    "require": {
        "propel/propel": "dev-master",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing software on a system.

Comment: Your php installation is missing the curl extension, therefore guzzle cannot be installed and the aws-sdk depends on guzzle.. As the error message says. However, your posted composer.json does not require the aws-sdk (if you do not require dev the dependencies of monolog, which include the aws-sdk). Are you sure your configuration is right? Check the composer documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

I was also facing this issue and stumbled upon this question. Yes, installing cURL was the solution.

**EDIT:**
Do remember to restart the server (just PHP/Apache) after the installation.

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart the server. You may need to restart PHP but restarting the machine or the web server wouldn't really help anything.

Comment: Oh yes, I just meant restart Apache along with PHP. Will edit the answer to reflect clearly.